# Error CS7036 with newly added code

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

Why am I getting this error...

I have a class called Product and this is part of the code:

```
public void insertProduct(int cid, string name, string price, byte[] image, int quantity, string desc, int company, int compid)
{

    DB db = new DB();
    db.openConnection();
    SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[8];

    parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@c_id", SqlDbType.Int);
    parameters[0].Value = cid;

    parameters[1] = new SqlParameter("@p_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    parameters[1].Value = name;

    parameters[2] = new SqlParameter("@s_qty", SqlDbType.Int);
    parameters[2].Value = quantity;

    parameters[3] = new SqlParameter("@price", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    parameters[3].Value = price;

    parameters[4] = new SqlParameter("@desc", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    parameters[4].Value = desc;

    parameters[5] = new SqlParameter("@img", SqlDbType.Image);
    parameters[5].Value = image;

    parameters[6] = new SqlParameter("@comp", SqlDbType.Int);
    parameters[6].Value = company;

    parameters[7] = new SqlParameter("@comp_id", SqlDbType.Int);
    parameters[7].Value = compid;

    db.setData("spr_insert_product", parameters);
    db.closeConnection();

}
```

I call this class from the Form "Add" Button

```
private void BTN_ADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TB_NAME.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter The Product Name", "Empty Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    if (TB_PRICE.Text == string.Empty && TB_QUANTITY.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Quantity and Price Can't Be Empty | But Can Be Equal To 0", "Empty Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else if (PB_BROWSE_IMAGE.Image == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Image Selected", "No Image", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    else
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        PB_BROWSE_IMAGE.Image.Save(ms, PB_BROWSE_IMAGE.Image.RawFormat);
        byte[] image = ms.ToArray();

            product.insertProduct(Convert.ToInt32(COMBO_CATEGORIES.SelectedValue), TB_NAME.Text,
                                 TB_PRICE.Text, image, Convert.ToInt32(TB_QUANTITY.Text), TB_DESCRIPTION.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("New Product Inserted Successfully", "New Product", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Under this code at the very end on line:

```
product.insertProduct(
```

is where I get this error and I can't figure out why?
Just for a reference... Everything was working fine until I added code to the method:

```
int company, int compid
```

to associate with 2 more columns added to the DB and also code:

```
parameters[6] = new SqlParameter("@comp", SqlDbType.Int);
parameters[6].Value = company;

parameters[7] = new SqlParameter("@comp_id", SqlDbType.Int);
parameters[7].Value = compid;
```

If I take this newly added code, I am not getting an error.
Can anyone spot what is wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: Please tag language you are using. I guess it is C#. Also what exactly is error (Error code might have multiple error messages). I only found this [CS 7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0694d671-ba52-4631-8771-ea5d64b7feba/cs-7036-there-is-no-argument-given-that-corresponds-to-the-required-formal-parameter?forum=csharpgeneral) and that seems descriptive enough - you are calling method and not passing enough parameters

Comment: The types in the product.insertProduct  are not matching the array of parameters you created

Comment: Yes... it's C#.

Comment: The Error is: "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'company' of 'Product.InsertProduct(int, string, string, byte[image], int, string, int, int)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Piro for your comment... Late night and I didn't see it:
Here is the code that did it:

```
 product.insertProduct(Convert.ToInt32(COMBO_CATEGORIES.SelectedValue), TB_NAME.Text,
                                 TB_PRICE.Text, image, Convert.ToInt32(TB_QUANTITY.Text), TB_DESCRIPTION.Text, TB_COMPANY.Text, TB_COMP_ID.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("New Product Inserted Successfully", "New Product", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```